# Issue with simple_form validation in fancybox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, fancybox-2

I am using simple_form inside a fancybox.

If i am not using fancybox, am able to do google's location autocomplete and simple_form validations using(validation true).

This things are not working inside fancybox.

Using fancybox2-rails (0.2.4)

```
  <%= simple_form_for @hotlist, :validate => true, :html => {:multipart => true, name: 'hotlist_resume'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Full Name' %>
    <%= f.input :email, as: :email, placeholder: 'Enter valid email address' %>
    <%= f.input :phone, input_html: {type: 'text'}, required: false %>
    <%= f.input :current_location %>
<% end %>
```

without fancybox:

```
<%= link_to 'Create Hotlist Resume', new_hotlist_resume_path, class: 'btn btn-inverse', style: 'font-weight: normal;' %>
```

WithFancybox

```
    <%= link_to 'Create Hotlist Resume', new_hotlist_resume_path, class: 'btn btn-inverse fancybox fancybox.ajax', style: 'font-weight: normal;' %>
```

Model validation

```
validates_presence_of :name, :current_location, :email, :phone
```

Comment: try initializing the form validation function INSIDE the `beforeShow` fancybox callback

Comment: simple_form handles without it.

Comment: so I don't understand what the issue is (if any) or if it is solved!?!?!

Comment: its not resolved.
If we added data-validate=true to form, Simple_form does validation based on validations in model. This is working when not using fancybox. It is not working fancybox. I need it to work in fancybox

Comment: well, you supposed to post the code you are using too, otherwise we can spend days just guessing.

Comment: added code in question